# Small o-complexity of $(\sqrt n)^\sqrt n=$

Tags: asymptotics

show that $(\sqrt n)^\sqrt n=o(2^{n^{0.6}})$

i just know that small o-complexity of $\sqrt n=o(n)$ but how to prove this

Comment: Could you provide the source? From where did you take this problem? A book, lecture notes...

Comment: This question has now two answers that are both absolutely wrong. That needs to be addressed.

Comment: @gnasher729 Are the tools from the linked question not enough?

Comment: @Raphael, I think they are and if the question is about taking those limits, it's not a question for CS.SE. But those answers were incorrect, by the time gnasher729 wrote the comment.

Comment: Agreed. Suresh, please read the [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth). If computing the limit is beyond you, [math.SE] would be the place to get help with that. Good luck!

Comment: That reference section could do with a section what happens when you take the logarithm on both sides. PS. The question is a nice example where drawing a graph and drawing conclusions will absolutely give you the wrong answer.